# Проблема с принятием сообщения от сервера (сокеты)

Tags: c, сокет, unix, snmp

Доброго времени суток! Нужно было написать программу, которая реализует snmpget протокола SNMP.
Пока начал просто с отправки пакета. 
Перед его отправкой я конечно же сделал snmpget и вывел пакет. Потом, соответственно его перекодировал и начал отправлять.
Так вот, отправляю пакет на 161 порт локал хосту, а в ответ ничего не получаю. В чем может быть проблема?

```
#ifndef CONFIG_H
#define CONFIG_H

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <linux/limits.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define ASN1_INTEGER             0x02
#define ASN1_OID                 0x06
#define ASN1_OCTET_STRING        0x04
#define ASN1_SEQUINCE            0x30
#define ASN1_NULL                0x05
#define ASN1_GET_REQUEST_PDU     0xA0
#define ASN1_GET_RESPONCE_PDU    0xA2

#define LEFT_BIT                 0x80

#define SRV_HOST "localhost"
#define SRV_PORT 161
#define CLNT_PORT 1610
#define BUF_SIZE 64

#define ALLOCATE_ARRAY(ptr, type, n) \
    ptr = ( type* ) calloc( n, sizeof(type) )

#endif

octet_t translate_char(char C)
{
switch(C)
{
    case '0': return 0x0;
    case '1': return 0x1;
    case '2': return 0x2;
    case '3': return 0x3;
    case '4': return 0x4;
    case '5': return 0x5;
    case '6': return 0x6;
    case '7': return 0x7;
    case '8': return 0x8;
    case '9': return 0x9;
    case 'A': return 0xA;
    case 'B': return 0xB;
    case 'C': return 0xC;
    case 'D': return 0xD;
    case 'E': return 0xE;
    case 'F': return 0xF;
    default:  return 0x0;
}
}


octet_t fill_octet(char *str)
{
/*
printf("%02X\n", translate_char(str[0]));
printf("%02X\n", translate_char(str[1]));
char first = translate_char(str[0]);
first = first << 4;
*/
return (translate_char(str[0]) << 4) | translate_char(str[1]);
}


octets_t get_raw_packet(char *str)
{
octets_t pck;
ALLOCATE_ARRAY(pck, octet_t, strlen(str));
size_t i, j = 0;
for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i+=2)
{
    pck[j] = fill_octet(&str[i]);
    j++;
}
return pck;
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int s;
    int from_len;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    struct hostent *hp;
    struct sockaddr_in clnt_sin, srv_sin;
    write(1, "\n\n\n", 3);
    s = socket (PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);
    memset ((char *)&clnt_sin, '\0', sizeof(clnt_sin));
    clnt_sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clnt_sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    clnt_sin.sin_port = htons(CLNT_PORT);
    bind (s, (struct sockaddr *)&clnt_sin, sizeof(clnt_sin));
    octets_t buf1 = get_raw_packet("302A02010104067075626C6963A11D020443F4A0E8020100020100300F300D06092B06010201190105000500");
    char *inbuf; ALLOCATE_ARRAY(inbuf, char, BUFSIZ);
    memset ((char *)&srv_sin, '\0', sizeof(srv_sin));
    hp = gethostbyname (SRV_HOST);
    srv_sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy ((char *)&srv_sin.sin_addr,hp->h_addr,hp->h_length);
    srv_sin.sin_port = htons(SRV_PORT);
    socklen_t *addrlen;
    ALLOCATE_ARRAY(addrlen, socklen_t, 1);
    sendto(s, buf1, strlen(buf1), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &srv_sin, sizeof(srv_sin));
   fd_set rfds, afds;
   int nfds=getdtablesize();
   FD_ZERO(&afds);
   FD_SET(s,&afds);
   while(1) {
     memcpy(&rfds, &afds, sizeof(rfds));
     select(nfds, &rfds, NULL,NULL,NULL);
     if ( FD_ISSET(s, &rfds) ) {
        from_len = recvfrom(s, inbuf, BUFSIZ, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clnt_sin, addrlen);/*recv (s, buf, BUF_SIZE, 0);*/
        write (1, inbuf, from_len);
     }
   }

    from_len = recvfrom(s, inbuf, BUFSIZ, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clnt_sin, addrlen);/*recv (s, buf, BUF_SIZE, 0);*/
    write (1, inbuf, from_len);
    close (s);
    exit (0);
}
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что что-то отправилось?  У вас отсутсвует опроос как завершилась `sendto`.

Comment: Добавил select, но что-то он все равно не хочет работать
Возможно что-то не так сделал?

Comment: А при чём здесь селект? `result = sendto(...) ; if (result<0) { perror("sendto"); }`

Comment: кхм, ну как бы strace показывает, что отправка была: sendto(3, "0*\2\1\1\4\6public\241\35\2\4C\364\240\350\2\1", 23, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(161), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 23

Comment: Тогда смотрите, кто на 161 порту сидит, Поставте ему debug и смотрите  логи.

Comment: 161 порт зарезервирован под snmp. daemon там находится

Comment: А почему вы в recvfrom() свой адрес задаёте? От кого вы собираетесь получать данные?

Comment: Да, я поменял это
Но проблему это не решает

Comment: Пока я вижу там `clnt_sin`. Посмотрите снифером. Перестартуйте  daemon  с дебуг, посмотрите его логи. Будет время, я скомпилирую вашу програму, посмотрю у себя.

Comment: Добавте вывод - netstat -plnu и /etc/snmp/snmp.conf